# How to dump network requests receive and send?

Tags: shell, networking, network-interface, reverse-engineering

I want to learn reverse app, I'm confused how to dump network of an app, I tried tcpflow, ngrep, etc. it works but the output data is not human readable, can you give me a linux command to get network receive / send data, from an app / hosts?
i try this

```bash
sudo ngrep -W byline port 80
```

ouput

```
interface: wlp1s0 (192.168.230.0/255.255.255.0)
filter: ( port 80 ) and ((ip || ip6) || (vlan && (ip || ip6)))
####
T 192.168.230.135:29464 -> 91.108.56.124:80 [AP] #4
POST /api HTTP/1.1.
Host: 91.108.56.124:80.
Content-Length: 148.
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
Connection: Keep-Alive.
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate.
Accept-Language: en-US,*.
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0.
.
.............g[c....x.F`$..>o-...O:2..3ib.W.q.._.,.)1.....k.........!..z...M^.g^...I.p...5.yx.Ys...Y*.m.. ....w...uK.%..0`....~.f.&...Q..br..W...3..
```

which is easy to read like a regular text string?

Comment: why do you expect the data to be human readable?

Comment: This is the actual data sent. It is most probably gziped or deflated.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)?  It's not only a packet capture program like `tcpdump` or `ngrep`, it's also a network protocol decoder/analyser.  i.e. it can make it easier to interpret the network traffic.

BTW, wireshark is almost certainly packaged for whatever distro you're running - e.g. on debian `apt-get install wireshark`.

Worth noting: `wireshark` itself is a GUI program (current version uses Qt, previous versions used GTK), but there is also a console version called `tshark`, which is useful if you need to run it remotely over an ssh session.  `wireshark` is also capable of analysing packet capture files (e.g. as produced by `tcpdump -w filename -s 0` or `tshark -w filename`) as well as live network capture.

Depending on your distro, `tshark` may be in the same package as `wireshark` or it may be in a separate package - e.g. on Debian, it's in the `tshark` package.

---

Also, if you're mostly interested in web traffic, [libwww-perl](https://metacpan.org/release/libwww-perl) (aka LWP, a perl library for writing web bots and similar tools) comes with a command-line tool called `lwp-request` (with aliases `HEAD`, `GET`, and `POST`) for extracting headers and/or data from URLs including the chain of request and response headers, and another called `lwp-dump` to *"See what headers and content is returned for a URL"*.

LWP is also very likely to be available as a package for your distro.  e.g., on debian, `apt-get install libwww-perl`